# Passing array of paths to "Route" throws error

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Whenever I am giving array of paths to `Route` it gives following error :

`meta.relativePath.startsWith is not a function`

Code snippet:

```
 <Route
          path={["/search", "/images", "/news", "/videos"]}
          element={<Results />}
 ></Route>
```

The tutorial which I was following was using older version of React router and thus they were also using  `Switch` and that's why it was working fine in the tutorial.

Since in v6 `Switch` is no longer available and I also tried to go through docs regarding how to pass array of path, but didn't find anything which can solve the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`react-router` v6 doesn't support passing an array of `path` in `Route`.

If you want to keep the same behavior, you need to separate it into multiple `Route` like this

```
<Route
  path="/search"
  element={<Results />}
/>
<Route
  path="/images"
  element={<Results />}
/>
<Route
  path="/news"
  element={<Results />}
/>

<Route
  path="/videos"
  element={<Results />}
/>
```

or a shorter way is to use `.map`

```
{
  ["/search", "/images", "/news", "/videos"].map((p) => (
    <Route key={p} path={p} element={<Results />} />
  ));
}
```

Comment: I tried to get things done using map, but it was showing that `path` does not match. But i now did it in other way and it is working fine. Thanks ❤